# node.js error upon client disconnect

Tags: node.js, server, socket.io

I'm using node.js and I get the error in the picture every single time a client disconnects (This happens when I just close the tab and I've also tried using socket.disconnect() on both the client and the server side)

[image: Error I'm getting]

here's my code

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(4000);
var fs = require('fs');

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('login', function(info)
  {
      fs.readFile("chatLog.txt", function(err, data)
      {
          if(err)
          {
              return console.error(err);
          }
          socket.emit('incomingMessage', data.toString());
      });
      socket.broadcast.emit('newUser', info);
  });
  socket.on('message', function(content) {
    console.log(content); 
    io.sockets.emit('incomingMessage', content);
  });
  socket.on('logout', function(name)
  {
     socket.broadcast.emit('incomingMessage', "user: " + name + " has logged out");
     //socket.disconnect();
  });
});
```

can anyone tell me how to disconnect without having the server crash with that error?

client side HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- This is the websocket SERVER -->
<script src="http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="client.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="loginDiv">
    username: <input type="text" id = "userName"><br>
    <input type = "button" id="login" value = "login" onClick="login()">
</div>
<div id="logoutDiv" style="visibility:hidden">
    <input type = "button" id = "messageRedir" value = "send message" onClick= "gotoMessage()">
    <input type = "button" id = "logout" value = "logout" onClick="logout()">
</div>
<div id="sendMessage" style="visibility:hidden">
    <input type = "text" id="messageBox"><br>
    <input type = "button" value="send message" onClick="sendMessage()">
    <input type = "button" value = "cancel" onClick="back">
</div>
<div id="msg"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Client side JS:

```
var userName = null;
var socket = null;
function login()
{

  socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
  userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
  document.getElementById("loginDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("logoutDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
  socket.emit('login', userName+ ' has connected');

  // Attach event handler for event fired by server
  socket.on('incomingMessage', function(data) {
     var elem = document.getElementById('msg'); 
     console.log(data);
     elem.innerHTML =  data + "<br>" + elem.innerHTML; // append data that we got back
  });
   socket.on('newUser', function(data) {
     var elem = document.getElementById('msg'); 
     console.log(data);
     elem.innerHTML =  data + "<br>" + elem.innerHTML; // append data that we got back
  });
}

function logout()
{
    document.getElementById("loginDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("logoutDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "";
    socket.emit('logout', userName);
    socket.disconnect();
    socket = null;
}

function gotoMessage()
{
    document.getElementById("loginDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("msg").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("sendMessage").visibility = "visible";
}

function back()
{
    document.getElementById("loginDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("msg").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("sendMessage").visibility = "hidden";
}

function sendMessage()
{
    var mess = document.getElementById('messageBox').value;
    socket.emit('message', mess);
}
```

Comment: can you show us the clientside code.

Comment: I've edited the post so that it shows the client code now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely in the logout function where you are using the socket (that is no longer active) to emit an event. You should use `io.sockets.emit` instead. I have some suggestions.

Instead of using the `socket.emit('logout', username)` event on the client side, use the built in **logout** event that gets fired when the user close the browser. That event is `disconnect`. You don't need to pass the username with each request either. You only need to pass it once with the login event. Then you can store the username on the server as a property of the socket.

## Client Side

```js
function login()
{

  socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
  userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
  document.getElementById("loginDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("logoutDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
  // just send the username
  socket.emit('login', userName);

  // Attach event handler for event fired by server
  socket.on('incomingMessage', function(data) {
     var elem = document.getElementById('msg'); 
     console.log(data);
     elem.innerHTML =  data + "<br>" + elem.innerHTML; // append data that we got back
  });
   socket.on('newUser', function(data) {
     var elem = document.getElementById('msg'); 
     console.log(data);
     elem.innerHTML =  data + "<br>" + elem.innerHTML; // append data that we got back
  });
}

function logout()
{
    document.getElementById("loginDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("logoutDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "";
    socket.disconnect();
    socket = null;
}
```

## Server Side

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('login', function(uxname)
  {
      // store username variable as property of the socket connection
      // this way we can handle the disconnect message later
      this.username = uxname;

      fs.readFile("chatLog.txt", function(err, data)
      {
          if(err)
          {
              return console.error(err);
          }
          socket.emit('incomingMessage', data.toString());
      });
      socket.broadcast.emit('newUser', uxname);
  });
  socket.on('message', function(content) {
    console.log(content); 
    io.sockets.emit('incomingMessage', content);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
       // don't use socket.broadcast.emit. at this point the socket is destroyed and you cant call events on it. That is most likely why you have the error.
       // use io.sockets.emit instead
       io.sockets.emit('incomingMessage', "user: " + this.username + " has logged out")
  });
});
```